# Retrofit Android локализация

Tags: android, retrofit

Имеется json, который возвращается от сервера

```
 {
  "error": false,
  "message": "Registered successfully",
  "user": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Faiz Khan",
    "email": "faiz@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male"
  }
```

или

```
 {
  "error": true,
  "message": "This email already exist, please login"
}
```

Имеется код отправки Post запроса и получение ответа:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    //Defining retrofit api service
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    //Defining the user object as we need to pass it with the call
    User user = new User(name, email, password, gender);

    //defining the call
    Call<Result> call = service.createUser(
            user.getName(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            user.getGender()
    );

    //calling the api
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            //hiding progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //displaying the message from the response as toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

По сути мы всегда получаем сообщения на английском. Мне хотелось бы локализовать сообщения.

Вместо сообщения мы будем передавать некоторый параметр (status), по которому можно определить какой ответ пришел и с помощью R.string выводить разные сообщения в зависимости от языка.

Теперь json приходит вида `{status: 101}` или статус с пользователем (статус может быть любое число).

Переделал класс модели:

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private int status;

    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;

    public Result(int status, User user){
        this.status = status;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }    
}
```

Переделал часть кода получения ответа

```
...
public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                int status = response.body().getStatus();
                Toast toast=null;
                switch (status){
                    case 101:
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_created, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        break;
                    case 102:
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_exist_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        break;
                    case 103:
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_creation_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        break;
                    case 104:
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_exist_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        break;
                    case 105:
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_exist_phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        break;
                }
                if(toast!=null){
                    toast.show();
                }
```

Но возникает ошибка с `int status = response.body().getStatus();`

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.activities.SignUp$2.onResponse(SignUp.java:154)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Из-за чего ошибка? и как исправить. Возможно вы посоветуете другой способ локализации сообщений

Источник, откуда взята информация [Ссылка](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial/)

**UPD PHP(SLIM)**

```
//registering a new user
$app->post('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (isTheseParametersAvailable(array('login', 'email', 'password', 'phone','gender'))) {
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();
        $login = $requestData['login'];
        $email = $requestData['email'];
        $password = $requestData['password'];
        $phone = $requestData['phone'];
        $gender = $requestData['gender'];
        $db = new DbOperation();
        $responseData = array();

        $result = $db->registerUser($login, $email, $password, $phone, $gender);

        if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
            $responseData['status'] = 101;
            $responseData['user'] = $db->getUserByLogin($login);
        } else if ($result == USER_CREATION_FAILED) {
            $responseData['status'] = 103;
        } else if ($result == USER_EXIST_LOGIN) {
            $responseData['status'] = 102;
        } else if ($result == USER_EXIST_EMAIL) {
            $responseData['status'] = 104;
        } else if ($result == USER_EXIST_PHONE) {
            $responseData['status'] = 105;
        }

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($responseData));
    }
});
```

Comment: а что нужно сделать то? ну в чем суть проблемы я че то не совсем понял

Comment: Может у Вас `progressDialog` `null` - на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: В HTTP предусмотрен заголовок `Accept-Language`. Клиент может в запросе передавать в нём интересующую локаль, а сервер, проверив заголовок возвращать сообщение на нужном языке.

Comment: @woesss я же указал, ошибка связано со строкой int status = response.body().getStatus();

Comment: @Романыч ошибка связана с int status = response.body().getStatus();

Comment: `response.code()` проверьте. И за одно `if (!response.isSuccessful()) Log.d(TAG, "ошибка: " + response.errorBody());` - всё это до обращения к `body()`

Answer (score -2):

Если вместо английского `essage": "Registered successfully` нужно выводить просто то же самое на русском то можно тупо сделать проверку типа\

```
public String getMessage(){

    if(status.equals("Registered successfully"){
    return: "Успешно" }return: "А тут второй вариант";
    }
```

Но я не уверен что так правильно так как не совсем понял что нужно иметь на выходе

Comment: И что я к каждому сообщению буду делать отдельный перевод? А если языков разных около 40?

Comment: В вопросе не было разговора про 40 языков. Тогда надо делать локализацию как уже советовали.

Comment: как? на сервере? А нельзя на Android сделать такую систему? Используя R.string? (Так как там локализация намного удобнее) и передавать некий статус

Comment: Никто не мешает в моем примере возвращать значение string.  Хоть 40 языков

Comment: Только локализацию придется делать ручками

Comment: На Андроиде сделать можно, но если Вам захочется изменить текст сообщения или добавить язык, то придётся обновлять приложение и заставить юзера это сделать. А когда локализация на сервере - Вы меняете что хотите и это отражается на всех, не зависимо от версии клиента. Но хозяин - барин, как говорится.

Comment: @woesss, хорошо вы меня убедили. Как на сервере определить язык? Использую SLIM(PHP). Код добавил выше

Comment: На стороне клиента получить https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639103 и добавить в заголовок `Accept-Language`. В PHP не шарю -  задайте конкретно вопрос с меткой PHP. Смысл в том что бы прочитать этот заголовок и выбрать соответствующий язык сообщений.